# Cursor indicates I can click to toggle "Ignore time filter" button, but it does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-dashboard

This is on Chrome (Version 75.0.3770.100) on Windows 10. In the flag dashboard on the Physics.SE site, when I want to click on the "Ignore time filter" button, the cursor changes to the finger when it's over the checkbox and "Ignore time filter" label, and I can click to toggle the checkbox.

But, the cursor *also* changes to the finger over the text "Show flags that are not normally shown immediately." However, clicking there does not toggle the checkbox despite the finger cursor.

If I could figure out how to take a screenshot that included the cursor, I'd show what I mean... but I can't seem to find a way without downloading/installing extra things that I can't do. Hopefully the description is enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox on macOS. The paragraph inherits the `cursor: pointer` styling from the parent `div`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXcRL.png

Comment: Had some reading comprehension issues here but it sounds like the problem i just that the secondary description text looks clickable but it's not.  That appears to be a styling issue I missed.  I can wire that up to be clickable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed.

I didn't expect the cursor style when I used the element.  I've wired it up so it does the same thing as clicking the text above it.

Comment: Looks like it's working. Thanks!